# Appending JVM parameter to the parameter specified explicitly in plugin configuration?

Tags: maven-3

Sometimes I need the parameter to be appended, instead of overriding the one in configuration:

for instance

```
mvn test  -DargLine="-Dportal.test=huge"
```

should be added to

```
<argLine>-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled</argLine>
```

so the result would equal to

```
<argLine>-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dportal.test=huge</argLine>
```

Could please anybody tell me if it is possible and how ?

EDIT: Please don't answer with " Why would you want to do that" kind of annoying questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used argLine but maybe this is what you are looking for.. i.e.:

```
<argLine>-DskipTests=true ${argLine}</argLine>
```

(I used skip tests as an example :))

Comment: Well I'm confused now, the surefire-plugin plugin Mojo has a parameter argLine. This param can be set either with JVM parameter -DargLine or <argLine> element in configuration. JVM param by default overrides the configuration....Now with your solution I suppose that I would have to call the JVM parameter name different than argLine, because it would get overriden the same way as it would so in the original scenario...so that <argLine>-DskipTests=true ${argLine2}</argLine>...Btw this example doesn't make sense argLine is for true JVM parameters that are applied to the forked test JVM processes